# $\inf$ and $\sup$ of two real random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, random, borel-sets

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two rrv’s. Prove that $\inf(X,Y)(w):=\inf \{X(w),Y(w)\}$,$w\in \Omega$ and $\sup(X,Y)(w):=\sup\{X(w),Y(w)\}$,  $w\in \Omega$ are also rrv’s.

In the book, definition of real random variable is given. I am confused how we’re going to prove this statement by using the definition. Also I know that the sum of random variables are random variables.

Comment: $\sup\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$ and $\inf\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$.

Comment: You should edit the title into something more informative.

Comment: So the sum of two rrv’s also rrv? Like $X(w)+Y(w)+|X(w)-Y(w)|$ ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: However, are'nt they continuous? So should we use the definition? Indeed, $\inf(X,Y)=\min(X,Y)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Observe that $\min(X,Y)> c$ if and only if $X>c$ and $Y> c$. Therefore
$$
\{\min(X,Y)> c\} = \{X> c\}\cap\{Y> c\}.
$$
So if $X$ and $Y$ are real random variables, then for every $c$ the sets $\{X> c\}$ and $\{Y> c\}$ belong to the sigma-algebra $\cal F$, and therefore...

Comment: For the $\{\max(X,Y)<c\}=\{X<c\}\cup\{Y<c\}$

Comment: @yorukobasi No, $max(x,y)<c$ iff $x<c$ **and** $y<c$.